# Xcode 10.2.1 hangs when building unity 2019.1.2 project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to do an iOS build for a unity project for the first time and have been able to export from unity without any errors.

When I "Run" project in Xcode it starts but then hangs. I've noticed thousands of warnings "Code will never be executed" with GenericMethods.cpp but no exceptions. I'm also getting tens of thousands of warnings from UnityRendering.h saying "This function declaration is not a prototype".

The files seems to be part of the Native code base so I'm not sure what to do or if so many warnings can cause the freeze.

Im setup as a developer in Xcode and am using "automatic signing" with the Team option selected. I don't think this is a profile issue since it would probably throw an error.

I've tried other suggestions of removing ProceduralToolkit (which is not in this unity version) as well as using command line Xcode to build.

Archiving the project hangs at 600 of 616.

Here's one example of the warnings in the unity code:

Classes>Unity/UnityRendering.h

[image: Screen-Shot-2019-07-02-at-12-46-44-PM]

Comment: Step 1) Fix all warnings.

Comment: That was part of the question. How do I fix warnings from native unity code? Or does this mean there is a version conflict with Xcode and unity. Sorry to speculate so much... perhaps by "fix" you mean something other than rewriting unity code.